# Magento Product Meta Title Not Populating

Tags: php, magento, seo

Maintaining a Magento site built by someone else, noticed the site owner had not populated **Meta Title**, **Description** & **Keywords** on a product level.  The default meta-information for the site populates into every product page.

After successfully populating these attributes for the store view, clearing cache, re-indexing, verifying the attributes are active, etc., the default meta-information for the site is still what populates the product page.

Seems like it would be a configuration issue, but at this point I'd like to rule out the chance that the original developer altered the core functionality somehow. I see where the `getTitle()` method populates the default meta-information when it can't find something more specific, so that's cool and it's doing so because there is no data for the title when it's rendering the page.

**Where would I find the method that creates/populates data for the product object when building a product page?**

If I find where that happens, I should be able to test for what is coming out of the database directly.

Or, if by reading this you realize I've missed checking a config option, would love to hear about that, too.

Answer (score 1):

The product meta titles are set in Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View in the _prepareLayout() method

See [here](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.7/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View.php#L58)